# Improving performance: reverse 3 chars then remove the 4th one, repeated until the end of a huge string

Tags: php

I need to do something like this in PHP:

1234 -> 321

1234123412341234 -> 321321321321

Reverse 3 chars then remove 4th one -> repeat until end of string.

What is the best method to do this? Performance is key. Currently I am doing it like this:

```
$data = str_repeat('1234', 5*1024*1024/4); //making 5 MB string
$start = microtime(1); //timing
$newdata = '';
$x = 0;

while($x < strlen($data)){
    $newdata .= strrev(substr($data, $x, 3));
    $x += 4;
}

echo 'took '.floor((microtime(1)-$start)*1000).' ms';
```

It takes ~180 ms in my case which is way too much, <30 ms would be acceptable. Any suggestions?

Regards

//EDIT
I made a code that does the same thing in Pascal, it takes on average 15-16ms:

```
procedure x2;
var
  data: string;
  newdata: string;//array of char;
  start: qword;
  x, n, l: integer;
  f: TFileStream;
begin
  data := DupeString('1234', 5*1024*1024 div 4);
  start := GetTickCount64;
  x := 1;
  n := 1;
  l := length(data);
  setlength(newdata, l-(l div 4));
  
  while x < l do begin
    newdata[n] := data[x+2];
    newdata[n+1] := data[x+1];
    newdata[n+2] := data[x];
    inc(n, 3);
    inc(x, 4);
  end;
  
  showmessage('took '+IntToStr(GetTickCount64-start)+' ms');
  
  //save modified string to file because I couldn't believe it's that fast
  f := TFileStream.Create('test.txt', fmOpenReadWrite+fmCreate);
  f.Write(newdata[1], length(newdata));
  FreeAndNil(f);
end;
```

If I run it 100 times it tooks <1600 ms:

```
var
  i: integer;
  q: qword;
begin
  q := GetTickCount64;
  for i := 0 to 100 do x2;
  showmessage('took '+IntToStr(GetTickCount64-q)+' ms');
end;
```

Well, I guess PHP is not as fast as native apps.

Comment: You can gain a very few ms with `$len = strlen($data)` before the loop, then `while ($x < $len)`

Comment: I tried this, this is weird because it should make it faster but it actually adds 20-25ms more

Comment: Just running the program with the loop body commented out takes 18ms on my system. Php is interpreted so I wouldn't expect it to be as fast as a compiled language for a task like this

Comment: @user1269348: for my part, the 1st time was longer (I guess some cache optimisations), then it went from 72ms to 69ms, with a very stable benchmark time for each version

Answer (score 0):

Your edit has anticipated my response;

Indeed, unless I missed something, you cannot really improve your actual Php code : you are using native functions when working on strings (like `substr()` and `strrev()`), which is fine because you leave the "hard work" to functions written in C. But of course, the main loop in written in Php, and in this case, it loops more than 5,000,000 times.

I see you tried it in Pascal; for my part I tested in Rust (but not very optimized code): 72ms in Php, vs. 7ms in Rust.

So indeed, imho if you need faster processing, try compiled languages!